# Terminate thread class mid-execution

Tags: python, multithreading, events, wxpython

In this program, a non-blocking thread is started upon pressing "Start Counter." This starts a thread class called "CountingThread." The thread works as it should (increments by 3 until it reaches 12, with sleeps in between).

However, I am attempting to implement a "Stop Counter" button, which will terminate the thread regardless of how far along the thread is in its execution.

**CountingFrame.py**

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
import wx
import time
import threading
number = 0
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class CountingFrame(wx.Frame):      
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # Attributes
        self._counter = wx.StaticText(self, label="0")

        # Layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        start_button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Start Counter")
        stop_button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Stop Counter")
        sizer.AddMany([(start_button, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER),
                       (stop_button, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER),
                       ((15, 15), 0),
                       (self._counter, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)])

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetMinSize((300, 300))        
        
        # Event Handlers
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, start_button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop, stop_button)
        self.Bind(EVT_COUNT, self.OnCount)

    def OnStart(self, evt):
        thread = CountingThread(self)
        thread.start()
        
    def OnStop(self, evt):
        CountingThread.stop()   ##### Need to replace this line #####

    def OnCount(self, evt):     
        val = str(int(self._counter.GetLabel()) + evt.GetValue())
        self._counter.SetLabel(val)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

## Runs on its own thread and calls CountEvent to increment num    
class CountingThread(threading.Thread):        
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """
        @param parent: The gui object that should recieve the value
        @param value: value to 'calculate' to
        """
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._parent = parent

    def run(self):
        """Overrides Thread.run. Don't call this directly its called internally
        when you call Thread.start().
        """
        limit = 5
        increment_amt = 1
        while increment_amt < limit:
            time.sleep(2) # our simulated calculation time
            evt = CountEvent(myEVT_COUNT)  
            wx.PostEvent(self._parent, evt)
            increment_amt +=1
    
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
    
## Performs the event: increments num by 3
myEVT_COUNT = wx.NewEventType()
EVT_COUNT = wx.PyEventBinder(myEVT_COUNT)
class CountEvent(wx.PyCommandEvent): 
    """Event to signal that a count value is ready"""
    def __init__(self, eid):
        """Creates the event object"""
        wx.PyCommandEvent.__init__(self, eid)

    def GetValue(self):
        global number
        """Returns the value from the event.
        @return: the value of this event
        """
        temp = number + 3
        return (temp)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = wx.App(False)
    FRAME = CountingFrame(None)
    FRAME.Show()
    APP.MainLoop()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

I tried implementing a timer that checked for a global variable's value, which would change when stop_button is clicked. However, I am honestly just uncertain how to stop the thread period, even from within the CountingThread class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Stop function to the thread, that toggles a variable.
Make that variable part of your `while` statement.
e.g.

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
import wx
import time
import threading
number = 0
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

class CountingFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # Attributes
        self._counter = wx.StaticText(self, label="0")

        # Layout
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        start_button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Start Counter")
        stop_button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Stop Counter")
        sizer.AddMany([(start_button, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER),
                       (stop_button, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER),
                       ((15, 15), 0),
                       (self._counter, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER)])

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.SetMinSize((300, 300))

        # Event Handlers
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStart, start_button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop, stop_button)
        self.Bind(EVT_COUNT, self.OnCount)

    def OnStart(self, evt):
        self.thread = CountingThread(self)
        self.thread.start()

    def OnStop(self, evt):
        self.thread.stop()   ##### Need to replace this line #####
        self.thread.join()
        print("Thread Terminated")

    def OnCount(self, evt):
        val = str(int(self._counter.GetLabel()) + evt.GetValue())
        self._counter.SetLabel(val)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

## Runs on its own thread and calls CountEvent to increment num
class CountingThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """
        @param parent: The gui object that should recieve the value
        @param value: value to 'calculate' to
        """
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._parent = parent
        self.terminate = False

    def run(self):
        """Overrides Thread.run. Don't call this directly its called internally
        when you call Thread.start().
        """
        limit = 20
        increment_amt = 1
        while increment_amt < limit and self.terminate is False:
            time.sleep(1) # our simulated calculation time
            evt = CountEvent(myEVT_COUNT)
            wx.PostEvent(self._parent, evt)
            increment_amt +=1
        return

    def stop(self):
        print("Stop")
        self.terminate = True

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

## Performs the event: increments num by 3
myEVT_COUNT = wx.NewEventType()
EVT_COUNT = wx.PyEventBinder(myEVT_COUNT)
class CountEvent(wx.PyCommandEvent):
    """Event to signal that a count value is ready"""
    def __init__(self, eid):
        """Creates the event object"""
        wx.PyCommandEvent.__init__(self, eid)

    def GetValue(self):
        global number
        """Returns the value from the event.
        @return: the value of this event
        """
        temp = number + 3
        return (temp)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = wx.App(False)
    FRAME = CountingFrame(None)
    FRAME.Show()
    APP.MainLoop()

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

Answer (score 1):

Bit of elaboration on Rolf of Saxony's answer:

Some languages, Python included, provide no way for one thread to kill another. That's because doing so is almost always a mistake. In fact, it is *always* a mistake for thread K (the "Killer") to kill thread V (the "Victim") if, at any point in its execution, thread V ever locks a mutex.

You might ask, *Why can't the kill operation automatically unlock any mutexes that are held by thread V?*

Threads communicate with each other by mutating shared data, and often it is important not to let other threads look at the shared data when one thread is in the middle of updating it. It could crash the program, or worse, if some thread gets a glimpse of shared data when a change is only half-way done. The whole point of using a mutex is to prevent any threads from seeing shared data when some other thread is half-way done changing it.

So, what happens if you kill a thread when the thread is half-way done changing something? Automatically unlocking the mutex would let other threads see the half-way-done change. Not unlocking the mutex would prevent any other thread from ever using that data again. Neither way is a winner.

Some older systems allow one thread in a program to kill another, and they trust you to use that power wisely. Other, mostly newer systems, Python included, just don't allow you to do it at all.

---

Threads should always cooperate with each other. If thread K discovers a reason why thread V should die, then it should *ask* thread V to please clean up any mess that it might be in the middle of making, and kindly commit suicide. And, of course, thread V should do exactly as it was asked.